# Twitter Bootstrap - Column not aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand why my "Employment Type" field is not lining up with the other positions on the form. Fiddle provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/GvjXE/. I think I'm using the control-label class properly, but, as a new bootstrap adopter, I might have made a mistake.
Here is a snip of the code but you can see a working copy on the jsfiddle listed above.

```
<label class="control-label" for="input04">Employment Type</label>
<div class="controls">
<select id="input04" name="EmpType">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>
```

^^ Not working

```
<label class="control-label" for="input05">Grade Level</label>
<div class="controls">
<select id="input05" name="Grdlvl">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>
```

^^ Working.

Comment: Your Gender controls' floats aren't being cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .clearfix to the .control div that wraps the radio buttons and it seems to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/GvjXE/7/

```
<div class="controls clearfix">
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input id="input03" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Male">Male</label>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input  id="input03" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Female">Female</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a bonus.. is there an easy way to have text in the drop down that disappears sort of like the First Name and Last Name fields listed above?

Comment: No, I don;t think you can have placeholder text in a select element. Normal practice would be to place something like "Please select:" as the first option.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be your inline radio buttons in the previous `controls` DIV. If you give them the class *container* too the Employment Level lines up correctly:

```
<label class="control-label" for="input03">
  Gender
</label>
<div class="controls container">
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input id="input03" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Male">Male
  </label>
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input  id="input03" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Female">Female
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be wrapping the entire control contents in a `control-group`. Like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Employment Type</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="input04" name="EmpType">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AZdwv/

Comment: Ken, thanks for the answer. I did try that and I get the same results. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/9mgae/

Comment: @weggie - You need to wrap EVERY group in control-group. http://jsfiddle.net/AZdwv/